# Simple Example to Export and Import a Dialogflow Agent in Python

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I'm having trouble executing a simple bit of code to export or import my Dialogflow agent in Python.  I'm not sure what is wrong with the below code and was hoping someone could help me out.  The Python dialogflow library documentation is confusing.

```
import dialogflow_v2
import os


os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="C:\\path\\to\\credentials.json"
project = "my_project"
client = dialogflow_v2.AgentsClient()
parent = client.project_path(project)
response = client.export_agent(parent)
response = client.import_agent(parent)
```

Comment: Looks like they use callbacks to handle the results of the import and export. maybe try that?

Comment: so just append this code?
    def callback(operation_future):
        result = operation_future.result()
    response.add_done_callback(callback)

Comment: what error you are getting?